# Is it possible to have a transparent actionbar without overlaying the view with the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay, transparency

I was able to make the action bar transparent using http://www.cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/. However I do not want the view to overlay with the action bar. I changed

```
  <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

to false but it lost the transparency.

EDIT: solved it using

android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" in my layout.

Comment: You can answer to your own question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to), so it will help other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" in  layout.
```

Here You Have to post your answer. So that it will Helps Other.chk https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to